# how to use Remote Service?

Tags: android, service

i`m trying to use Remote Service btween two simple application, But 
it`s not easy to me. 
So any advice you have will help me.

here`s my case.

I made one app which is playing Music in service, 
There are two components. 
one is Activity controlling service by using three buttons, 
play,pause, stop. 
and it is working fine.

and another one is just simple Activity which also has four buttons 
bind,play,stop,unbind. 
when i click bind, it`s confirmed by Toast msg, but when i click play 
button,it occurs error.

i want to control first activity`s Music playing service in second 
Activity. 
So i`m trying to use remote service. 
i made same .aidl file in each app project. 
In aidl file, i defined methods  "playing","stoping" 
and i implement those methods in Music service class, 
implementation is simply use intent and startService & stopService.

In DDMS there is "java.lang.SecurityException : Binder invocation to 
an incorrect interface" 
that`s the case  what i`m doing.

So please tell me what`s the problem. 
any advice could help me. 
thanks 
Gun.

Answer (score 1):

First, get rid of the AIDL. You do not need a remote service for a music player application. AIDL and remote services are for communication *between applications*, not for within a single application.

[Here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/WeatherPlus/) showing local binding to a service, without AIDL, if it helps you determine how best to use the binding pattern.